# how to input ffmpeg to live loop 6 or 8 hours?

Tags: ffmpeg, live

I'm currently using this, and i want it to be loop 6 or 8hours, how to edit this?

ffmpeg -re -y -i HayDay.mp4 -c:a copy -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 96k -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1080:-1 -r 30 -g 60 -tune zerolatency -f flv -maxrate 2000k -preset veryfast "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/FB-222653387188323-0-AbwCY_lFkOiN-FhG"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer is to add `-stream_loop -1 -t 6:00:00` before `-i HayDay.mp4` but the better answer is to encode it once and then apply the above options to the encoded file and stream that.